# SQL Maximum Recursion Causes Failure

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I can't remember where I got this, but probably SO so sorry to original poster. I have been using it wonderfully for quiet some time with perfect results. Today however I ran into a problem. I am running it through SSRS with a list of around 1500 item. Naturally someone is going to click "ALL" even though they really never will want all, however, when they do, is errors out

> An error occurred during local report processing. An error has
>   occurred during report processing. Cannot read the next data row for
>   the data set Accounts. The statement terminated. The maximum recursion
>   100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

here is the code: Is this a SQL thing or a code thing?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseCSV] (@CSV_STR VARCHAR(8000),@Delimiter varchar(20) )
 RETURNS @splittable TABLE (ID int identity(1,1), CSVvalues VARCHAR(256) )
AS
BEGIN  

-- Check for NULL string or empty sting
    IF  (LEN(@CSV_STR) < 1 OR @CSV_STR IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END

    ; WITH csvtbl(i,j)
    AS
    (
        SELECT i=1, j= CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@CSV_STR+@Delimiter) 

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT i=j+1, j=CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@CSV_STR+@Delimiter,j+1)
        FROM csvtbl
        WHERE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@CSV_STR+@Delimiter,j+1) <> 0
    )   

    INSERT  INTO @splittable  ( CSVvalues)
    SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@CSV_STR,i,j-i)))
    FROM    csvtbl 

    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Save everyone some time. Its not exactly a duplicate but the same response would fix it. It is a SQL this :

[The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion error showing in SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220778/the-maximum-recursion-100-has-been-exhausted-before-statement-completion-error-s)

Answer (score 0):

The default maximum number of recursions for a recursive CTE is 100. You need to set `OPTION MAXRECURSION number` on your `SELECT` statement where number is anything between 0 and 32767 and 0 is no limit. Obviously be careful setting the number to 0 as you could potentially get an infinite loop.